# How do I view the definition of a UDF in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, function, ssms, tracking

I was given a user created function in `SSMS` that executes some SQL statements and I am trying identify what it's running specifically. How can I do that? Using the console in `SSMS`?

Comment: What you're looking for is SQL execution plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the correct permissions (possibly a big "IF" depending on your environment), you can access user defined functions the same way you would access, for instance, stored procedures.

Under the database name, expand the `Programmability` folder, then expand the `Functions` folder. If you know whether it's a Table-valued Function or a Scalar-valued Function, look in the appropriate folder. If you're not sure, you'll have to hunt around for it.

Once you find the function, right click on the function name. In the dialogue box that opens, select `Script Function as` -> `CREATE to` -> `New Query Editor Window`. This will open a query window with the text of the function in it.

I always use the `CREATE to` option. You can get there faster by clicking on `Modify` in the initial dialogue, but the script that gets generated there is an `ALTER FUNCTION` statement, where you could accidentally change the code. Using the `CREATE to` option opens a `CREATE FUNCTION` statement, which, if you accidentally run it, will throw an error because the function already exists, and you won't have done any harm.

[image]